# Paging a TableView, but DataSource/Delegates not executing

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, delegates, datasource, paging

I am having problems with getting the datasource or delegate methods to execute.

I am using a Paging View in my MainViewController and it pages just fine, but when it comes to the tableview is blank and when I put a breakpoint where the datasource methods are, it never gets called.

MainViewController to Load the View

```
 if ((NSNull *)controller2 == [NSNull null])
{
    if(page == 2)
    {
        controller2 = [[requestDetailThreeViewController alloc] initWithRequestNumber:[request objectForKey:@"RequestID"]];
        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller2];
        CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * 2;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        controller2.view.frame = frame;
        [scrollView addSubview:controller2.view];
    }

}
```

The TableViewController (requestDetailThreeViewController)

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
   [super viewDidLoad];



[History fullHistoryWithBlock:^(NSArray *netMessages, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {

        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", nil) message:   [error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil), nil] show];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Number of Historical Entries: %d", [netMessages count]);

        self.historyFromNet = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:netMessages];
    }

} forID:requestNum];

}


   - (id) initWithRequestNumber:(NSString *)requestID
 {

     if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"View" bundle:nil])
  {
      self.requestNum = requestID;
  }
  return self;

}
```

(Apologize for the spacing on the 2nd block of code, hard time getting it into code mode.
It executes these two methods, but it doesn't execute the datasource methods I also have in the class.

In the XIB file I have the owner of the xib set to the requestDetailThreeViewController
The tableView is set to datasource/delegate and view

If I set the tableview to hidden in the ViewDidLoad, it does disappear.

I just can't get it to execute the methods to populate the table.

Update:

Some more information-

The View XIB only has a TableView in it, no controllers.

Thanks!
Alan

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a child view controller so you will need to use the UIViewController containment methods.

Something like:

```
    controller2 = [[requestDetailThreeViewController alloc] initWithRequestNumber:[request objectForKey:@"RequestID"]];
    [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller2];
    [self addChildViewController:controller2];
    CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * 2;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    controller2.view.frame = frame;
    [scrollView addSubview:controller2.view];
    [controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Also consider using a UIPageViewController for a paging view rather than doing it manually via   a scroll view

Comment: Hello, I feel like this is the problem, but it is still not working. I hadn't thought about UIPageViewController. I used Apple's page control example as the springboard to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set `self.tableView.delegate = self` in     `-(void)viewDidLoad`
that is

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: I forget the `self.tableView.dataSource = self`. Have a try.

Comment: I did add that, still does not execute the datasource methods.